# Awstats logformat typo?

Tags: nginx, awstats

I've been through the awstats docs for a while now, it just seems to be failing with the Logformat.

I'm using the following in awstats,

```
LogFormat = "%host - - %host_r %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot %otherquot"
```

(from nginx)

```
 log_format   main
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
    '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log main;
```

Sample hits:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qD9PKN52

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `"` from around some of the objects on your log lines and you have them around others that don't need them.

Try

```
 log_format   main
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log main;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's true. Removing "" from $status and putting them to $request should solve the problem.

Also if you already have tons of "corrupted" logs like I do, you can run:

```
sed -i "s/00\]\ /00\]\ \"/g" access.log
```

and

```
sed -i "s/\(HTTP\/[0-9].[0-9]\)\ \"\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\"/\1\"\ \2/g" access.log
```

This would make the old logs usable for awstats.